# Prevent type mismatch error indications in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, editor

In Intellij IDEA, I have a Scala case class expecting Longs as arguments. The arguments passed in are numbers, which intellij interprets as Ints and reports an error on it. The code compiles without errors or warnings, so he compiler (and I) don't care. It's pretty easy to fix by putting a l after the number, but that is cumbersome and does not increase readability. Is there a setting somewhere in Intellij Idea to fix this behavior?

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open bug (see also the linked issues):

- [SCL-7729](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7729) Highlight error with implicit conversion of covariant type